# Using keyboard shortcut E silently fails if there's a pending suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, keyboard-shortcuts

On Q&A pages, using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>E</kbd> opens the post editor (either inline if you have [full edit privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), or in a new page).

However, this fails if there's a pending suggested edit; in that case, the post is selected (visible through the gray background) but nothing else happens.

It would be nice if it would show the error message (and scroll towards it, if it's a long post):

[image]

or open the review dialog:

[image]

depending on your privilege level.

Comment: Re *"using the keyboard shortcut E opens the post editor"*: Only if enabled in preferences?